# Bootstrap styling Rounded Corners

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know why my fields in Bootstrap don't have the rounded corners.  When I choose the Form Control input field in other parts of my website the corners are well rounded.

[image]

```
              <div class='form-group'>
                <div class='col-sm-12'>
                  {{ trans('Suburb') }}:
 {{ Form::text('suburb', Input::get('suburb') ? e(Input::get('suburb')) : '', array('class' => 'suburb form-control')) }}
                 </div>

              </div>
              <div class='form-group'>
 <div class='col-sm-4'>
                {{ trans('Postcode') }}
{{ Form::text('postcode', Input::get('postcode') ? e(Input::get('postcode')) : '', array('class' => 'postcode form-control')) }}
                  </div>

                <div class='col-sm-4'>
                 {{ trans('Region') }}:
{{ Form::text('region', Input::get('region') ? e(Input::get('region')) : '', array('class' => 'region form-control')) }}
                 </div>
               <div class='col-sm-4'>
               {{ trans('State') }}:
{{ Form::text('state', Input::get('state') ? e(Input::get('state')) : '', array('class' => 'state form-control')) }}
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
```

In Chrome when I turn these settings off, it makes it round

```
media="all"
.user-profile .btn-group .form-control, .browse .btn-group .form-control {
border-top: 0px;
border-bottom: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

[image]

How do I change the above code permanently?

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML without the template tags?

Comment: Have you used a web inspector to verify if anything is overriding the bootstrap css?

Comment: Are you missing the reference to your css on this page?

Comment: @MichaelBurns yea I appended that to the code

Comment: Are you using any other css besides bootstrap that may be changing your form-controls or input fields?

Comment: this is what is impacting it media="all"
.user-profile .btn-group .form-control, .browse .btn-group .form-control {
border-top: 0px;
border-bottom: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}, but its all from the bootstrap css

Answer (score 15):

change `.form-control` properties

```
.form-control{
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Francisc0 according to `Caniuse`, you shouldn't use vendor prefixes until your clients uses Firefox 1.X or Chrome 3 and below.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy The answer is 2 year old. I would suggest **autoprefixer** for the vendor prefixes to CSS rules using values from **Can I Use** https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil thank you for a link. But anyway, even 2 years ago FF 1.x and Chrome 2 was outdated.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy It is all depends on the project requirement 

Answer (score 9):

I see you have:

```
border-radius: 0px;
```

This makes square corners.

Comment: What is the code to make round borders in bootstrap?  I just use class= form control in all my pages to make the fields and they are all round, except in this page

Comment: Try border-radius: 4px;

Answer (score 7):

Fixed it

```
 * {
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px !important;
         -moz-border-radius: 4px !important;
              border-radius: 4px !important;
      -webkit-border-top: 4px !important;
         -moz-border-top: 4px !important;
              border-top: 4px !important;
      -webkit-border-bottom: 4px !important;
         -moz-border-bottom: 4px !important;
              border-bottom: 4px !important;
    }
```

Comment: this is overkill and you won't be able to use border-radius on any other element anywhere, at all.  Just override it in your css (which should be included in your page after bootstrap)

`.form-control { border-radius: initial }`
or
`.form-control { border-radius: 0px }`

that way you are only targeting the form inputs

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want your form controls to be rounded?
If that is the case, you use this:

```
.form-control {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;

  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Or if you want it square, you just put 0 for values.

You can experiment on this link with the border radius:
http://border-radius.com/